# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport renders all elements

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to render a List but It renders all the elements like a classic ngFor

```
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="16">
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let i of nums" style="color: aliceblue;">
        {{ i }}
    </div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the height of the viewport to indicate the number of elements to show at a time?

in the html - add a class to the viewport element :

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="16" class="viewport">
```

in the css:

```
.viewport {
    height: 48px; /* shows 3 elements at a time */
}
```